# How far does a boycott need to go before it's considered illegal?

Tags: united-states, business, freedom-of-speech

The story [here](https://kiwifarms.net/threads/brianna-wu-john-flynt.6034/post-942632) is as follows:

> The /tg/-goers among us may know it better, but several months ago, a small outfit called Postmortem Studios released a card game called "Gamergate: the Card Game." The online store, DriveThruRPG, picked it up, and, as it turns out, this triggered Evil Hat Productions employees something fierce, so a number among them (Chris Hanrahan, Brian Engard, Daniel Solis) complained to DTRPG to stop carrying the card game with Brian Engard and Chris Hanrahan in particular threatening to pull Evil Hat products from the store if they did not remove the card game. Since FATE and other assorted Evil Hat productions are a much bigger moneymaker than than the GG card game, it came to no surprise that DTRPG pussied out and removed the product.

> Evil Hat Productions, like many SJWs, is oblivious of the fact that blacklisting people you don't like and threatening others not to deal with them can be pretty fucking illegal depending on the circumstances. In particular, this falls cleanly under FTC's anticompetitive practices list for a single-firm conduct "refusal to deal" violation. **Considering how Evil Hat sells their own card game products, Postmortem Studios is a clear direct competitor and therefore this constitutes an attempt to monopolize by way of curtailing a competitor's market access**.

I feel like the guy here is reaching hard. Has he ever heard of freedom of association and freedom to boycott? Also I don't think the motive he is presenting is sound. Is it politics or monopolizing business?

Comment: There are circumstances in which boycotts, particularly so-called "secondary boycotts" have been held unlawful in the US.  I would need to review sources before giving any answer about this specific case or where the line is now drawn -- the cases I recall are over 50 years old -- one was a boycott of an ice delivery company -- and may no longer be good law.

Comment: Shorter: I don't think that the legal claim stands up to scrutiny. The analysis is rather extended and arcane.

Comment: Note that your question is asking about two distinct concepts: boycotts, and refusals to deal. They are both potentially actionable -- despite First Amendment concerns -- but they are analyzed differently. This sounds like it could be a viable refusal-to-deal case, though it's been a while since I've had to remember exactly how that analysis works.

Comment: A boycott is when consumers choose not to consume a product or service. This is not a boycott.

Comment: @bdb484 A refusal to deal seems to violate free association rights.

Comment: That is a common argument, but the Supreme Court has rejected it. *Lorain Journal Co. v. United States* (1951)